# After building a docker image how can I run the image without pushing to docker hub?

Tags: docker

The docs are not very clear to me. I run `docker build -f .` in the Dockerfile directory, it seems to build successfully, great. I am not sure what to do next, I take a look at the docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ it tells me `When you’re done with your build, you’re ready to look into Pushing a repository to its registry.`

Which takes me here https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerrepos/#contributing-to-docker-hub I have no interest in publishing it or creating an account.

My other option is to name the build I guess, right? If I run `docker build -t <nodebb> .` then I get `file exists: .`. If I run `docker build -f <nodebb> .` then I get `no such file or directory: nodebb`.

So I am kind of lost, I wish I could understand the Docs better but I don't and would appreciate the guidance. Thanks!

Comment: `docker build -t my_tag .` should work, and you should be able to run `docker run my_tag`. Can you show the complete output of `docker build -t my_tag .`?

Comment: Oh wow that worked, maybe because I was using <>

Comment: But the run process is not working `docker build -t nodebb`  works then `docker run nodebb` give me `unable to find image 'nodebb:latest' locally`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your issue with tagging: You cannot use `<>` in tags

The error that you saw was because '<' and '>' are interpreted by bash. `docker build -t <nodebb> .` tries to do the following:

1. It reads the file `nodebb` and pipes it into `docker build -t`.
2. It takes the output of `docker build -t < nodebb` and writes it to the file `.`

This fails for several reasons:

- `-t` expects an argument, the tag name
- the file `.` already exists (that's the error you saw)

Generally, you can avoid this by escaping the argument:

```
docker build -t "<nodebb>" .
```

However, this will result in another error:

```
Error parsing reference: "<nodebb>" is not a valid repository/tag
```

For good reasons, `<>` are not allowed in tag names. Instead, use a valid tag:

```
docker build -t nodebb .
```

---

#### Running an image without a tag

You can also run a built image without a tag; if you build an image, the last line will always be something like this:

```
Successfully built 028edf7c13d1
```

You can run that image with `docker run 028edf7c13d1`.

Comment: Ok cool then thats the problem last line is `The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1`